# Is there any point inside the cavity of a uniformly charged "non-conducting" object (not of a particular shape) where the electric field is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

It is well known that the electric field inside the cavity of a conductor is zero. The same can't be said in case of a non conductor. Although its easy to show that the field inside a concentric sphere + spherical cavity combination is zero everywhere inside the cavity, when we change the shape or position of the cavity this result seizes to exist. This makes me think if at any point inside such a cavity does the electric field become Zero??

Answer (score 0):

There could be or not be depending on the distribution of the charge. So, your question is too general to answer it correctly.

Comment: The generality was intentional. For example, Gauss law isnt just true for some special geometry right? Its independent of what shape your surface is. Similarly for the question, does there always exist atleast one point inside the cavity where the field is zero? If your answer was no to this, can you walk me through how you got to this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution of charge is spherically symmetrical about the center of the cavity, then the electric field will be zero at all points inside.

Comment: Can you clarify you statement? If the charge distribution is spherically symmetric in a non spherical solid? Or are you talking about the spherical solid-spherical cavity case that i mentioned in my question?

Comment: I'm assuming that the cavity and the charge are spherical. This would be the requirement for using Gauss's law.

Comment: But since the solution for that symmetry is easily available in most EMT books, there wouldn't be any point in me asking about it here. Thanks for your input though.